# .Net Core 3.1 WPF repository building from GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, build

I faced the problem of building the WPF repository. The repository is cloned from GitHub has changed the branch to release/3.1. I'm trying to build using command .\build. Returns an error:

> C:\Users\libvi.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk\1.0.0-beta.19474.3\tools\Tools.proj
> : error MSB4236: the specified "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" SDK could not be
> found.

Before that, the Build project.proj from the same package conflicted with the .Net Core version, this was solved by installing the .Net Core SDK 2.1.503 and creating an environment variable MSBuildSDKsPath pointing to this SDK. I build on Windows 10 1903.

All SDK and targetpack packages from 4.5.1 to 4.8 are installed. cmake 3.16.0, Python 3.7.4, Visual Studio 2019 are installed too. The project has a dependency on .Net Framework 4.7.2 and it is installed.

Maybe some parameters need to be specified in the building script, or some dependencies are not resolved?

Has anybody faced with such errors?

Comment: Is there a global.json file somewhere on your disk? if so make sure the version is correct. If it didn't work I suggest clearing cache and maybe uninstall and install netcore sdk using visual studio installer.